# SWT: How to redisplay new contents of a CTabItem

Tags: swt, ctabitem

I have a CTabFolder with one of its CTabItems which may change its contents on a given user action. But I don't know how to force the display once the contents have changed. I get the tab item blank; if I resize the window suddenly everything appears.

I'm not posting the code because I did some wrapping in Scala, but this is basically what I'm doing:

The CTabItem has a ScrolledComposite, set with setControl()

The ScrolledComposite contains a Composite

everything else is under this Composite

When the contents need to be changed, I take the existing CTabItem object, set it to a new ScrolledComposite, with a new Composite, from which hangs the new contents.

Calling redraw() and update() on the CTabFolder object doesn't do it... What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling layout()?

Comment: Yep, on the CTabFolder and on the ScrolledComposite that's set to the CTabItem. Doesn't work :(

Comment: I got it! I needed to call the layout(boolean,boolean) overload, with (true,true). I'll accept your answer, it led to the solution by looking a bit more at the API.